# powershell session in conemu is not seeing an odbc driver

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, conemu

If I open a powershell session normally I can run a script that uses the "PostgreSQL ANSI" odbc driver without issue.

If I open a powershell session in conemu (same arch, same user) I get a "data source name not found..." odbc error which means its not seeing the driver.

Why can't powershell see it in the conemu session?

Comment: Same path? Same environment variables?

Comment: The all look the same except for a bunch of ConEmu env vars

Comment: Run ProcessExplorer and compare executable paths and other properties of both PowerShell.exe processes.